# Postgres: After inserting value returns primary key and need to update column using returned primary id

Tags: postgresql, update, cte

In a single query, I need to perform Insert and update on the insertion row. For example, I have a set of columns and its value to be inserted after getting the primary key, I need to update another column on the same row.
I tried below query it does not work. Please help

```
With tempvar as (
  INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, col3)  
  VALUES ('colval1','colval2','colval3')   
  RETURNING primarykeyid  
)
update table_name  
    set column_to_be_updated  = concat('value', 'value') 
 where primarykeyid  = (select * from tempvar)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a separate update?

Comment: Why don't you provide the concatenated value directly in the `VALUES` clause?

Comment: Reason for concat i want to update column value as combining hash value with primary key value. I tried above query but it does not work for me. @ mustaccio

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, col3, column_to_be_updated)
  VALUES ('colval1','colval2','colval3', concat('value','value')) `

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do what you want with a request like:

```
WITH tempvar AS (
   INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, col3)
   VALUES ('colval1','colval2','colval3')
   RETURNING primarykeyid
)
UPDATE table_name
SET
    column_to_be_updated = concat('value', 'value')
FROM
    tempvar
WHERE
    table_name.primarykeyid  = tempvar.primarykeyid
```